# Elixir: Capturing the rest of a map using pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

I want to simultaneously match on a specific key in a map, **and** capture the rest of that map.  I was hoping something like this would work:

```
iex(10)> %{"nodeType" => type | rest} = %{"nodeType" => "conditional", "foo" => "bar"}

** (CompileError) iex:10: cannot invoke remote function IEx.Helpers.|/2 inside match
```

The goal is to write a set of functions which take a map, pattern match on one of the map's fields, and perform some transformations on the rest of the map.

```
def handle_condition(%{"nodeType" => "condition" | rest}) do
  # do something with rest
done
def handle_expression(%{"nodeType" => "expression" | rest}) do
  # do something with rest
done
```

But it looks like I'll need the callee to pass the nodeType separately unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I would like this syntax. I was just about to ask the same question and had guessed exactly the same syntax
`def update_document(%{id: id, revision: revision | rest}) do
    # couchdb stuff here
  end`

Comment: General note, the field `nodeType` indicates you may be better served using a `struct` as opposed to a mere map. See http://elixir-lang.github.io/getting-started/structs.html Without knowing your exact use case, I cannot state for sure, but the usage depicted is a code smell to me you are not using the best tool available.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can easily capture the whole map - maybe this will be enough?

```
def handle_condition(all = %{"nodeType" => "condition"}) do
  # do something with all
end
```

Or:

```
def handle_condition(all = %{"nodeType" => "condition"}) do
  all = Map.delete(all, "nodeType")
  # do something with all
end
```

Comment: It's a shame that `%{"nodeType" => "condition" | rest}` doesn't work, just like the spread operator in JS: `{nodeType: 'condition', ...rest}`

Answer (score 5):

Another nice way of achieving this is by using [Map.pop/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#pop/3):

```
def handle(%{} = map), do: handle(Map.pop(map, "nodeType"))

def handle({"condition", rest}) do
  # ... handle conditions here
end

def handle({"expression", rest}) do
  # ... handle expressions here
end
```